# Importing Datastore entities into Eclipse emulator

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-tools

I am trying to run a Google App Engine Java application locally.
I have installed the Cloud Tools for Eclipse and configured my project and the project starts OK.

I also see the Datastore Admin.

However, I don't see how I can import Datastore entities into Datastore Admin in Eclipse. I tried to follow the same instructions as for importing the entities into local emulator, however the import does not happen.

I can run the emulator using gcloud and import data there, however my app running in Eclipse does not seem to work with that emulator.

So two questions:

1. Can I configure Eclipse to use the gcloud Datastore emulator instead of running one separately?
2. Can I import Datastore entities into Eclipse run emulator?

Answer (score 0):

1. [Cloud Tools for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/) doesn't include an explicit separate emulator. In order to use the Datastore Emulator please refer to the [following section of the documentaiton](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator) in order to understand how to run it and [this section](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/emulator-export-import) to understand how to export and import emulator data. Notice that you just basically need to send an HTTP request (more specifically a POST request in the case of importing entities) with either a [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) or a similar command.
2. To interact with the Datastore instance (import entities, export entities, etc.) in a local server you can either use the Cloud Client Libraries for Java or third-party libraries like Objectify.
   Follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/usingclientlibraries) section of the documentation to configure Eclipse to use the Cloud Client Libraries in a Local Server. And an example of how to use it [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library)
   Follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/objectify) part of the documentation in order to configure Objectify when running applications locally, and all the relevant examples on how to load, save and delete data [here](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/BasicOperations#loading-saving-and-deleting-data).

Comment: So essentially the answer to both my questions in NO. What you are suggesting is I use Google Cloud Datastore from my Google Cloud Project. This is not very efficient at all.

Comment: The [solution](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/objectify) suggested switches [the bundled datastore emulator](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator) and uses the gcloud-based emulator and a third party library ([Objectify](https://github.com/objectify/objectify)) for entities manipulation.

Comment: In my application, we do not use Objectity, we directly use the Datastore APIs. So this does not work.

Comment: Notice [here](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/objectify#switching_datastore_emulator) that all what is required is to use a library that supports the `DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable` which is the case for the [Java Client Library](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/index.html?com/google/cloud/datastore/package-summary.html). If the env variable is set, then your application will look for the emulator and not the Datastore instance hosted on GCP.

Comment: So i tried this and does not work. I am not sure, if it is using the emulator or the local datastore emulator running in eclipse. How do i verify this? I am using <dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
 <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
 <version>1.9.74</version>
</dependency>   in my POM.  Do I need to use the datastore client specifically for this to work?

Comment: Can you add information about which steps you followed and the error log you're getting?